# How would you say "see me" in latin?

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

In the context of being a person that is ignored by others, how would you say "see me" in Latin?

Comment: Do you mean anything particular by "see me" besides "look at me"? The former is a bit awkward on its own in English.

Comment: No, not "look at me". Think of it as a movie title about that person mentioned above. Something like a cry "please, [see me]", but without "please". I mean, "see" is more in general, "look at" is like here and now.

Comment: By "see" do you mean "perceive" or "look specifically at"? English uses the same word for both, but in Latin they're distinct.

Comment: @Draconis I mean see like in "don't ignore me" or "talk to me [in general, not specifically here and now]".

Answer (score 6):

If you want to say "look at me" in the context of "hey, please, look at me now!", then one option would be:

> attende me!

This is the [imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#Latin) of the verb [attendere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attendo#Latin). The above expression is for the singular case, i.e. if you want one person to look at you. If you want a plurality of individuals to look at you, then the plural person is required:

> attendite me!

Maybe, if you want to stress the fact that the person is being ignored, as you suggest, you could say something like "do not ignore me!". In that case, you could use verbs like [*neglegere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neglego#Latin), [*oblivisci*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obliviscor#Latin), [*ignorare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignoro#Latin), or [*praeterire*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praetereo#Latin).

Following several comments below, two options are:

> ne + subjuntive

(taking care of number, i.e. singular or plural) and

> noli + infinitive

(*nolite* if plural)

For example:

> ne neglegas me!

or

> noli neglegere me!

Comment: Also consider the verb [respicio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Drespicio)

Comment: I like the first suggestion: it reminds me of the *O Vos Omnes: "O vos ómnes qui transítis per víam, atténdite et vidéte: / Si est dólor símilis sícut dólor méus." The last option isn't grammatical, though: you can't form negative commands that way.

Comment: I'm really not sure attendo is the right verb here. In my experience (and my dictionaries seem to agree), although it does mean 'pay attention,' it's in the sense of 'apply one's careful attention to,' 'set one's mind to,' or 'watch/observe/study closely,' not merely in the sense of 'see' or 'not ignore.' Even in the quotation that brianpck mentions above, attendite doesn't appear to mean the same thing as the videte that follows it – in fact, I think videte is closer than attendite to what the original poster has requested.

Comment: Without being a latin expert, I think I agree with @cnread. "Attendite me" seems more like "look at me here and now" (having the english meaning of "attention" in mind), while I'm searching for something like "nec ignora me", but not as a negation, that is "see me".

Comment: @cnread I think [this example](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2021%3A5&version=VULGATE;NIV) from the Vulgata is in the required sense, but sure, maybe there is a more precise term.

Comment: @brianpck How would a negative command be?

Comment: Eccl./Vulgate Examples: [ne+subjunctive (1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub_tuum_praesidium#Latin), [(2)](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Lc.html#x1_30), [noli (nolite if pl.)+infinitive](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/html/Mt.html#x7_1)

Comment: @Rafael mmm, so the imperative can only be used in the "affirmative" sense? I guess is similar in Spanish, e.g. _come!_ and _no comas!_...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use *nē* followed by an imperative, only *nē* with subjunctive or *nolī* with infinitive. Amusingly, *nē* with imperative makes me think of an Ancient Greek-speaker unfamiliar with Latin, because the direct translation of that is perfectly good Ancient Greek.

Comment: @luchonacho: Actually, I think the example from the Vulgate that you linked to in an earlier comment supports my point. Look at the translation that's given: 'Look at,' which is exactly what the original poster has said he doesn't want.

Comment: @Draconis: ne + imperative is early (or maybe just colloquial) and poetic.  Plautus's Curculio has 'ne time' (520) and Vergil's, Aeneid has 'equo ne credite, Teucri' (2.48) and 'tu ne cede malis' (6.95).

Comment: @cnread Ah, interesting! Ty!

Comment: @cnread To be honest, the question is far from clear. I hope the OP could add more details, because as brianpck pointed out, "see me" in English is rather odd.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:

> *animadverte me*

or

> *animadvertite me*

The singular and plural imperative respectively of ***animadvertere*** - to turn or give mind to, to take notice of, to pay heed to, to consider, to observe.

Unfortunately, it was also used metaphorically to mean to take notice of a fault, and therefore, to censure or to punish.  But it is, nevertheless, used straightforwardly in the more neutral sense of simply noticing something.  For example:

> *... sic **animadverto** plerosque in magistratibus ...*
>
> ... and in the same way **I notice** that many of those who hold magistracies ...

Cicero, *De Legibus*, 3.48 (trans. Clinton W. Keyes)